# Gitlab CI can't clone gitlab repo

Tags: token, fatal-error, gitlab, runner, gitlab-ci

Has anybody has same problem?

I connected Gitlab ci with Gitlab. When test run Gitlab CI can't clone Gitlabs repo. 
Got this error:

```
cd /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds && git clone http://gitlab-ci-token:
<mytoken>@gitlab.xlab.si/primoz_godec/scrum_app.git project-3 && cd project-3 && git checkout
<othertoken>
Cloning into 'project-3'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8188
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5774

Comment: Thaks! But I already read this and don't help me. I think problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that http clone has been disabled on Gitlab. After enabling it everything was ok.